# Increasing Gain of OpAmp Design - increase or decrease drain current?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I was reading one of Razavi's op-amp design examples (telescopic fully diff) and he mentions how to increase the gain.

[image]

[image]

Notice in the highlighted part, he uses an equation for gmro but there is drain current on the numerator and the denominator? So increasing or decreasing drain currrent will change gain?

How does he then simplify that and reduce that reducing the drain current will increase gain?

Answer (score 0):

The equation has the square root of the drain current on the numerator but drain current in the denominator.

So the gain will go down as the square root of the current as it increases - this is consistent with the statement that decreasing drain current will increase gain.

Decreasing drain current will have other effects though such as noise and bandwidth so may not be a good solution.